# When running a code to log in to a system with a username and password I get the error 'secret' is not defined

Tags: python, syntax-error, undefined, user-input

When running a code to log in to a system with a username and password I get the error `'secret' is not defined`, how can I get it to stop saying that and to run normally?

This is the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Samuel\Documents\School\Computing\NEA - H\Program.py", line 16, in 
>       while username != secret:
>   NameError: name 'secret' is not defined

This is the code:

```
from random import randint

import os

import time

import sys



#xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx



username = ""
while username != secret:
username = input("Please enter the username: ")
if username == secret:
    print("Thank you. You have entered the correct username")
else:
    print("Sorry the value entered in incorrect - try again")


password = ""
while password != password:
password = input("Please enter the password: ")
if password == password:
    print("Thank you. You have entered the correct password, You are now in the menu system")
else:
    print("Sorry the value entered in incorrect - try again")





def online():

time.sleep(1)

print("Welcome Teacher")



logIn()



#xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx



def addStudent():

print("Loading student creator...")

time.sleep(1)

studentFile = open("Student_Details.txt","w")

ID = randint(1,1000)

surname = input("Surname: ")

time.sleep(1)

forename = input("Forename: ")

time.sleep(1)

DOB = input("Date of Birth: ")

time.sleep(1)

age = input("Age: ")

time.sleep(1)

homeAddress = input("Home address: ")

time.sleep(1)

homePhone = input("Home phone number: ")

time.sleep(1)

gender = input("Gender: ")

time.sleep(1)

tutor = randint(1,48)

time.sleep(1)

print("Writing to 'Student details.txt' now")

time.sleep(1.5)

email = (forename + surname + str(ID) + "@treeroadschool.net")

studentFile.write(str(ID) + "\n")

studentFile.write(surname + "\n")

studentFile.write(forename + "\n")

studentFile.write(str(DOB) + "\n")

studentFile.write(str(age) + "\n")

studentFile.write(homeAddress + "\n")

studentFile.write(homePhone + "\n")

studentFile.write(gender + "\n")

studentFile.write(str(tutor) + "\n")

studentFile.write(email + "\n")

studentFile.close()

print("Student data stored")

    #xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

def logOut():
print("Logging out...")
sys.exit()

#xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

def viewStudent():

print("MENU")

print("Choose one of the students by their number:")

print("><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><")

time.sleep(1)

print("1-25")

time.sleep(1)

choice2 = int(input("Choice? "))

print("><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><")

time.sleep(1)

if choice2 == 1:
    studentFile1 = open('Student_Details_01.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile1.readlines())

elif choice2 == 2:
    studentFile2 = open('Student_Details_02.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile2.readlines())

elif choice2 == 3:
    studentFile3 = open('Student_Details_03.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile3.readlines())

elif choice2 == 4:
    studentFile4 = open('Student_Details_04.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile4.readlines())

elif choice2 == 5:
    studentFile5 = open('Student_Details_05.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile5.readlines())

elif choice2 == 6:
    studentFile6 = open('Student_Details_06.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile6.readlines())

elif choice2 == 7:
    studentFile7 = open('Student_Details_07.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile7.readlines())

elif choice2 == 8:
    studentFile8 = open('Student_Details_08.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile8.readlines())

elif choice2 == 9:
    studentFile9 = open('Student_Details_09.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile9.readlines())

elif choice2 == 10:
    studentFile10 = open('Student_Details_10.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile10.readlines())

elif choice2 == 11:
    studentFile11 = open('Student_Details_11.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile11.readlines())

elif choice2 == 12:
    studentFile12 = open('Student_Details_12.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile12.readlines())

elif choice2 == 13:
    studentFile13 = open('Student_Details_13.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile13.readlines())

elif choice2 == 14:
    studentFile14 = open('Student_Details_14.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile14.readlines())

elif choice2 == 15:
    studentFile15 = open('Student_Details_15.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile15.readlines())

elif choice2 == 16:
    studentFile16 = open('Student_Details_16.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile16.readlines())

elif choice2 == 17:
    studentFile17 = open('Student_Details_17.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile17.readlines())

elif choice2 == 18:
    studentFile18 = open('Student_Details_18.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile18.readlines())

elif choice2 == 19:
    studentFile19 = open('Student_Details_19.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile19.readlines())

elif choice2 == 20:
    studentFile20 = open('Student_Details_20.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile20.readlines())

elif choice2 == 21:
    studentFile21 = open('Student_Details_21.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile21.readlines())

elif choice2 == 22:
    studentFile22 = open('Student_Details_22.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile22.readlines())

elif choice2 == 23:
    studentFile23 = open('Student_Details_23.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile23.readlines())

elif choice2 == 24:
    studentFile24 = open('Student_Details_24.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile24.readlines())

elif choice2 == 25:
    studentFile25 = open('Student_Details_25.txt', 'r') 
    print (studentFile25.readlines())


else:
    sys.exit()

#xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

def viewReport():
print("Loading Report...")
time.sleep(1)
studentFileReport = open('Student_Details_Report.txt', 'r') 
print (studentFileReport.readlines())

#xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

time.sleep(1)

print("><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><")

print("MENU")

print("Choose one of the options by their number:")

print("><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><")

time.sleep(1)

print("1: Add student")
print("2: Log out")
print("3: View student")
print("4: View report")
time.sleep(1)

choice = int(input("Choice? "))

print("><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><")

time.sleep(1)



if choice == 1:
addStudent()

elif choice == 2:
logOut()

elif choice == 3:
viewStudent()

elif choice == 4:
viewReport()

else:
sys.exit()
```

Comment: What is `secret`? It's a Python name for an object. Where are you defining it and what is the object it's meant to be a name for?

Comment: Do you mean the text "secret" and "password"? `if password == password` will always be true.  By  the way, your indentation seems to be wrong for the `while` loops, or is that an issue when you copied the code?

Comment: @PeterWoods secret is the correct username.

Comment: @cdarke No it made me do the indentations when i copied the code. I want it so that when you enter the username and password then access a system if you get them correct.

Comment: @SamSoffe but where is `secret` defined? It's not the same as `"secret"`, which is a string.

Comment: @PeterWood I dont know aha, im not very good at python.